# coldfusion custom tag return variable

Tags: coldfusion, custom-tags

I have a custom tag that displays the resume info to the browser of a user when a userid is passed to it. I want to return a variable with the html output to the calling page so that it can be used by a cfc. Can any one please comment on how to return the html in a variable? Is below the right way? And the calling page will look like

```
In custom tag <cfset caller[attributes.returnVar] = '#cv_content#'>

calling page <cf_cv_info user_id="295725" returnVar="foo">
```

thanks

Comment: To put html code into a variable, use the cfsavecontent tag to create the variable.  Then use Scott's answer to return it to the calling page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside your custom tag you can use the `caller` scope, which is a reference to the page that called the custom tag.

**DISCLAIMER** This is not really 'best practice' as custom tags really should not reach outside of themselves - even though ColdFusion allows it. But this should work.

Inside your custom tag:

```
<cfset caller[ attributes.returnVar ] = 'moo' />
```

Inside your .cfm that calls the custom tag.

```
<cf_myCustomTagThatSetsSomeValue userid="12345" returnvar="someValue" >
<cfdump var="#someValue#" />
```

*Edited based on Adam Cameron's and Joe Rinehart's comments*

Comment: I acknowlege the opinion expressed in the 2nd paragraph, but I don't share it.

Comment: I am sure you meant `<cfdump var="#somevalue#">`

Comment: I agree with @scott-stroz, but I think a custom tag can be coded to be clear it's "breaking out" into the caller scope. Have an attribute "returnValue" which takes a string, and that string will be used as a value to be set in the caller scope. Similar to how `<cfinvoke>` works with the same-named attribute.

Comment: @JamesAMohler Correct. Has been fixed.

Comment: @DanBracuk Does not surprise me that you do not share that opinion.

Comment: When two people have different opinions, it is clear that each person was able to form one.

Comment: Not what I meant. Does not surprise me that you don't agree using `caller` scope is NOT best practices.

Comment: Nothing - CFCs, custom tags, any encapsulation should "reach" outside of itself.

If you're going to touch the caller scope, use an attribute to pass in the variable name to set. This at least allows the caller to prevent collision with its own variables.

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs!

Comment: @Joe Rinehart This does not prevent collision between calling page variables & variables created via the custom tag's caller scope. It just makes it clearer to a new developer that an attribute, used as a caller scope key, should not be duplicated in the calling page.

Comment: Native tags like CFHTTP return variables for the calling page to use, so I reckon it is OK, to use the caller scope in a custom tag, as long as it is well documented. A key aspect of a custom tag & cfmodule is to sandbox input [attribute] variables...